# java null pointer exception in android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

in my mainactivity:

```
count=count+1;
//the problem seems to be in this line of code below
String fileName=f.getFileName(count).toString();
// the method below invokes a method from another class. it works fine so please ignore
helloTxt.setText(readText.readTxt(fileName));
```

f is an object of class FileName from which i get back the filename:

```
public class FileName {

    String file;
    public String getFileName(int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (count==1)
        {
            file.equals("textone");
        }

        if(count==2)
        {
            file.equals("texttwo");
        }
        return file;

    }



    }
```

Log Cat:

```
03-19 12:02:00.554: D/AndroidRuntime(5550): Shutting down VM
03-19 12:02:00.554: W/dalvikvm(5550): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418342a0)
03-19 12:02:00.562: E/AndroidRuntime(5550): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 12:02:00.562: E/AndroidRuntime(5550): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testflashfile/com.example.testflashfile.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 12:02:00.562: E/AndroidRuntime(5550):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
03-19 12:02:00.562: E/AndroidRuntime(5550):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
03-19 12:02:00.562: E/AndroidRuntime(5550):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-19 12:02:00.562: E/AndroidRuntime(5550):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
03-19 12:02:00.562: E/AndroidRuntime(5550):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-19 12:02:00.562: E/AndroidRuntime(5550):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-19 12:02:00.562: E/AndroidRuntime(5550):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
03-19 12:02:00.562: E/AndroidRuntime(5550):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 12:02:00.562: E/AndroidRuntime(5550):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-19 12:02:00.562: E/AndroidRuntime(5550):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
03-19 12:02:00.562: E/AndroidRuntime(5550):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
03-19 12:02:00.562: E/AndroidRuntime(5550):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 12:02:00.562: E/AndroidRuntime(5550): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 12:02:00.562: E/AndroidRuntime(5550):     at com.example.testflashfile.FileName.getFileName(FileName.java:11)
03-19 12:02:00.562: E/AndroidRuntime(5550):     at com.example.testflashfile.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
03-19 12:02:00.562: E/AndroidRuntime(5550):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5163)
03-19 12:02:00.562: E/AndroidRuntime(5550):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
03-19 12:02:00.562: E/AndroidRuntime(5550):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
03-19 12:02:00.562: E/AndroidRuntime(5550):     ... 11 more
03-19 12:02:11.164: I/Process(5550): Sending signal. PID: 5550 SIG: 9
```

All the activities are listed in the manifest. So any help which would fix this problem is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In getFileName() , did you initialize file object?

Comment: `equals` just return `true/false` instead of assigning value to other variable use `=` instead of `equals`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In place of

```
file.equals("textone");
file.equals("texttwo");
```

use

```
file = "textone";
file = "texttwo";
```

There are some steps you should take before using a method. See [`API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

See the documentation of [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method:

> Compares this string to the specified object.

It does NOT assign the value. to assign a value use `=` operator.

> And why it is throwing `NullPointerException`:

By default the instance fields of a class are initialzed to their default value. the reference type are assigned with default `null`. and when before `file.equals("textone");` executes, `file` variable is assigned with `null` and causes NPE.

Comment: thanks Azodious. problem solved. will accept your answer in 10 minutes

Comment: glad that could help. :)

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. It helped a lot in understanding the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
file.equals("textone");
```

with

```
file = "textone";
```

And

```
file.equals("texttwo");
```

with

```
file = "texttwo";
```

You are getting NPE for String file.

Answer (score 1):

This means you are accessing a null value

```
file.equals("textone");
```

First you need to intialize file with a String

```
file = "textone";
file = "texttwo";
```

equals is for comparing not for assign

Here file is null

Comment: Thanks PSR and ling.s